# Swift: how to check responds to and assign var declared in protocol as optional

Tags: swift, protocols, xcode6, option-type, optional-variables

protocol declaration:

```
@objc protocol LeftSideMenuViewControllerProtocol {
    var containerShouldPerformContentSegueWithIdentifier:((segueIdentifier: String, object: AnyObject!) -> Void)! {set get}
    optional var containerShouldResizeLeftMenuToValue:((CGFloat) -> Void)! {set get}
}
```

usage:

```
override var leftEmbedNavigation: CommonNavigationController? {
        willSet{
            if let nav = newValue {
                if let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as? LeftSideMenuViewControllerProtocol {
// non optional var, all good
                    vc.containerShouldPerformContentSegueWithIdentifier = {
                        [weak self] (segueIdentifier: String, object: AnyObject!) in

                    }
// optional declaration, cannot assign
                    vc.containerShouldResizeLeftMenuToValue = { [weak self] (newConstraintValue) in

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I check var implemented and how do I assign on?

Comment: Why are you using variables instead of proper delegate methods?

Comment: @akashivskyy using closures/blocks much more efficient, readable and useful from my point. In Objective-C task like that solves so easy, could not understand why do protocols has "optional" method and var if there is not documented way to work with?

Comment: As for now, you cannot assign to a protocol's optional variable (it may be a bug). You can follow [the related ADF thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/995076) if you want.